# Is it possible to set the default web site to redirect to a virtual directory in IIS

Tags: iis, redirect, defaults

Can you set up a website to make a default redirect to a virtual directory?

I tried to do this but it overrode every single website in my setup to that redirect.

I want to be able to open http://mywebsite/ and have that redirect somewhere.

Answer (score 2):

For IIS 6, [set the content source to "Another directory".](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/6b855a7a-0884-4508-ba95-079f38c77017.mspx?mfr=true)

IIS 7 introduces [URL rewriting](http://blogs.iis.net/bills/archive/2008/05/31/urlrewrite-module-for-iis7.aspx) which lets you easily build a rule to do this redirect.

Comment: but when I did this it overrode every single virtual directory.  I didn't select override all my virtual directories but it still did it.

Comment: Metabase keys are inherited by default, so if you set this key on your root, and none override it, it may get inherited.  I would consider it a bug that this does not work the way you expected.  If I'd have known you did this already I would have suggested one of the redirect options (JavaScript or ASP).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried editing/creating the Default.html in your wwwroot folder?

The following Javascript will redirect to where you want:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
    window.location = "http://mywebsite/virtualfolder"
//-->
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

I would do the redirection from /default.asp. You can use something like:

```
<%
' code to check the request here
...
' Redirect to directory of your choice
response.redirect "http://myserver/somedir/"
%>
```

Though note that this won't be transparent to the user. They will see the URL they typed in change.

JR