# Bind an IIS application to the root IP address

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, iis, ip

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to set the default web site to redirect to a virtual directory in IIS](https://serverfault.com/questions/25632/is-it-possible-to-set-the-default-web-site-to-redirect-to-a-virtual-directory-in)

I'm running [BugNet](http://www.bugnetproject.com/) on my server using IIS 7.0. The application folder is in the 'Default Web Site' node, along with 'aspnet_client'. To get to the BugNet panel, I have to navigate to `10.10.10.10/bugnet`. When I go to `10.10.10.10`, it shows the default IIS welcome page. How do I bind the root IP address to the BugNet application?

Answer (score 1):

Simple way in IIS 7.X is to just use an HTTP redirect to /bugnet on the default website. Check the box that says "Only redirect requests to content in this directory (not subdirectories)."